# Replicating clash royale coin animation

Tags: reactjs, animation, next.js, web-applications, mantine

I'm working on an app where users earn coins, and I want to add a cool animation similar to Clash Royale when coins are gained. Here's the Clash Royale animation for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaAN-r2EOsc or https://lottiefiles.com/animations/coin-collect-GMznH8RzOB

I'm using Next.js and Mantine for my app. Any ideas how I can replicate the clash royale animation?

I haven't created an animation yet because I do not know how to make animations, I have never made animations before.